# Adjust text size in order to fit in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, flexbox

I have several divs containing various text (headers, paragraphs, ...) with font sizes in em.
I want to detect if there is an overflow in these divs and then iterate while decreasing the font size until everything fit in the div.

Right now my `scrollHeight` is always equal to the `clientHeight` and I do not detect the overflow.

My divs are using flexbox and **cannot** have a fixed size in pixels!

```js
var fitDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-slide-fit]");
fitDivs.forEach(function(fitDiv) {
  if (fitDiv.scrollHeight > innerHeight(fitDiv)) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(fitDiv, null);
    var innerHeight = el.clientHeight
    for (iFontSize = 20; iFontSize > 10; iFontSize--) {
      fitDiv.style['font-size'] = iFontSize + 'px';
      if (fitDiv.scrollHeight < innerHeight) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container>div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column" data-slide-fit="">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" data-slide-fit="">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>This is a an ven very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching a little bit on google, I found a possible solution to check if the container div have contents overflowing its size.

So I made a function where you pass the container and then check if content is scrolling or not, if yes, it returns `true`. While it returns true, I keep your 
function to make the font smaller. Take a look at the snippet to see if this helps you.

Now it is checking the width overflow also, if you want just height, adjust the if inside the `checkOverflow`function.

```js
function checkOverflow(element){
  if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight ||
    element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
    return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
};


var fitDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-slide-fit]");
fitDivs.forEach(function(fitDiv) {
  if (checkOverflow(fitDiv)){
    for (iFontSize=20; iFontSize > 10;iFontSize-- ){    
      fitDiv.style['font-size'] = iFontSize + 'px';
      if (checkOverflow(fitDiv) == false){
        break;
      }
    }
  }              
});
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width:400px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:aqua;
 }
.container > div {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
}
h2{
font-size: 2.5em;
}

p{
font-size:1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="column" data-slide-fit="">
   <h2>Column 1</h2>
   <p>This is a very very very very very very very  very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text</p>
  
  </div>
  <div class="column" data-slide-fit="">
   <h2>Column 2</h2>
   <p>This is a an even very very very very very very very very very very  very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text</p>
  
  </div>
 


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that may work. you could test and see the number of letters the div can contain until it reaches an overflow state. lets say for example you found it to be 100 letters. then use an if statement that checks if the length of the string is greater than 100 letters. If so decrease the font size lets say to 16px.

Then you can check then number of letters with 16px size will cause the div to reach an overflow state and add an else if statement that checks if the length of the string exceeds this amount the font size changes again.

something like:-

```
if (string.length > 100) {
    iFontsize = 16px;
} else if (string.length > 500) {
    iFontSize = 14px;
}
```

This is just what you can call pseudo code you can customize it to your needs.

Comment: Yea. That's why I told you check the amount. keep typing until overflow occurs and the count the number of letters.